# Socket.io serverside broadcast

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to update an array on the server and broadcast it to all clients. The problem I am facing is that I need the client parameter to broadcast. On the server:

```
    var socket = io.listen(8000);
    var plateaus = [];

    setInterval(function () {
        plateaus.push('new data');
       -- send the updated array to all clients --
    }, 1000);

    socket.sockets.on("connection", setEventListeners);

    function setEventListeners(client) 
       // loadExistingPlayer(client); <- normally I use the client param
    }
```

How do I broadcast the updated array? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

answer on my own question (hope I will help anyone in the future).

You can store the client parameter in an array and access it anytime:

```
var socket = io.listen(8000);
var plateaus = [];
var clients = []

setInterval(function () {
    plateaus.push('new data');
    for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
       clients[i].emit('updata all clients',  plateaus)
    }
}, 1000);

socket.sockets.on("connection", setEventListeners);

function setEventListeners(client) 
   console.log('new client');
   clients.push(client);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you connect your client, wouldn't you just `emit` an event from your server and your client could listen to that event with `on(event, cb)`?

From the Docs: http://socket.io/docs/

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
```

Comment: yes... but how do I trigger the event in the servers interval

Comment: You could put the emitter within your setInterval.

Comment: see my answer, that is what I wanted to know :D